# Base Adapter getCount return total size

Tags: android

I have one Object which contains 5 lists, I need to return the size of every list, with 1 list it's ok, I do it like this, the information is displayed successfully.

```
 public int getCount() {
         return items.getLive().size();
        }
```

but then I tried like this, I know this may be dumb

```
public int getCount() {
return items.getLive().size()+items.getReceived().size()+items.getProcessing().size()+items.getSent().size()+items.getPacked().size();
        }
```

but I get

> out of index

Comment: Can you people at least explain why you give a - ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getView` method is only accessing items in the `List` you get from `getLive()`. If you want to show the items from every one of your lists, you need to access the data in each of those lists appropriately in `getView`.

Comment: i'm sorry could you please be more specific , you say, i live 'getLive.size();' in get count and do
'holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getLive().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());' for every list ?

Answer (score 0):

The `getCount` method is used to tell the number of items in the adapter. So if you overwrite the return value of `getCount` it will call the `getView` method as many times. 
If you want to get the sum of `items.getLive().size()+items.getReceived().size()+items.getProcessing().size()+items.getSent().size()+items.getPacked().size();` you should probably create another public method say `getTotalSize()` which returns the above value.